# max value of a list (of string items)

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

```
Heroes =['Superman','Batman','Dudley Do-Right','Luke Skywalker']
max(Heroes)
'Superman'
```

Can someone please explain why the above result is 'Superman' not 'Dudley Do-Right'?

`len(Heroes[0])` is 8

`len(Heroes[2])` is 15

I'm confused.

Comment: I'm personally confused why `Batman` isn't the max.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are compared by lexicographical ordering, not by length. `S` comes after `D` in the alphabet:

```
>>> 'Superman' > 'Dudley Do-Right'
True
```

An inefficient way to replicate what `max()` does, would be to *sort* the input sequence and pick the last value for the result. So `[20, 10, 8, 15]`, when sorted, puts `20` last and that's what `max()` returns. Sorting the strings in `Heroes` results in `Superman` being listed last.

If you wanted to find the *longest* string, use the [`key` argument to `max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
max(Heroes, key=len)
```

Here, instead of comparing values in `Heroes` directly, `max()` compares the values by the return value of the `key` argument; now the value for which `len()` returns the largest value is returned as the maximum.

Demo:

```
>>> Heroes = ['Superman', 'Batman', 'Dudley Do-Right', 'Luke Skywalker']
>>> max(Heroes, key=len)
'Dudley Do-Right'
```

Comment: Oh, i did not know that as i'm an amateur. Thank you for your explanation. :)